# Are there different results, depending on how you uninstall an Android app?

Tags: applications, google-play-store, settings, uninstallation

When uninstalling an Android app, is there any resultant difference between any of the following three procedures:

1. Find the app in the Play Store, and select "Uninstall"
   or
2. Open Settings, Select Apps, find the app in the list of apps, and select "Uninstall"
   or
3. Open Settings, Select Apps, find the app in the list of apps, and select "Clear Cache", then "Clear Data", then "Uninstall"

Specifically, does any of these options leave more behind than another option (or written conversely, does any one of these options do a better job cleaning up during an uninstall)?

Answer (score 1):

No. All of these have the same result.

Comment: To give some background: in all 3 cases, the job will be done by the same program (the "package manager") – which does take care to remove all cache and data of the app along the lines anyway.

Comment: But there's something I've noticed, the data in sdcard/Android/data remains untouched. In all three methods.

Comment: Especially that directory "should be" taken care of – that's exactly the argument used why apps shouldn't use just some random directories on the card, but that specific one (`/sdcard/Android/<package_name>`), so the package manager easily can take care of. If you encounter that, it must be a bug in your ROM. But as you said it happens in all 3 cases, that again renders this answer correct: no difference, same result :)

Comment: I no longer have SoundCloud on my phone, but http://imgur.com/52H6F50